# A possibly elegant way to compose and write proofs

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, first-order-logic

I have always observed proofs requiring complicated structure of proposition, either as the premise, as the conclusion or in the middle of proof construction. I have also felt that readers feel difficult understanding the logical structure of the proofs, as they are written in daily English. The constructor may have experienced the logical flow, but he/she has to present the proof in daily language. From my observations, I felt it necessary to indicate the use of logical rules at least implicitly in proof presentation. For instance, when we see an existential proposition, we would like to eliminate the existential quantification and enter a subproof with a much simpler proposition as the premise. The introduction of a new constant symbol should be implied in the proof presentation. I'd like to use an example to show such an implicit logical style.

Our task is to prove the following proposition, which is a step in proving the implicit function theorem in real analysis:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\textrm{Given an open set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$, suppose that $\left(x_{0},u_{0}\right) \in S$, where $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $u_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$.}\\ 
&\textrm{Then there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $x_{0}$ such that for all $x \in N$, $\left(x,u_{0}\right) \in S$}. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Below is my proof.
The fact that $S$ is open leads to the following premise:
\begin{equation}
\forall x \in S, \exists \delta > 0, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+m}, \lVert y-x \rVert < \delta \longrightarrow y \in S.
\end{equation}
We also have the following premise:
\begin{equation}
x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \wedge u_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{m} \wedge \left(x_{0},u_{0}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+m}.
\end{equation}
We wish to deduce the following conclusion:
\begin{equation}
\exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \lVert x-x_{0}\rVert < \delta \longrightarrow \left(x,u_{0}\right) \in S.
\end{equation}
First of all, replacing $x$ with $\left(x_{0},u_{0}\right)$ in the first premise and the fact that $\left(x_{0},u_{0}\right) \in S$, we get:
\begin{equation}
\exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \forall u \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, \lVert \left(x-x_{0},u-u_{0}\right)\rVert < \delta \longrightarrow \left(x,u\right) \in S.
\end{equation}
Introducing a constant symbol $\delta_{0}$, we introduce the following premise:
\begin{equation}
\delta_{0} > 0 \wedge \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \forall u \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, \lVert \left(x-x_{0},u-u_{0}\right)\rVert < \delta_{0} \longrightarrow \left(x,u\right) \in S.
\end{equation}
This proposition can be decomposed into two separate deductions:
\begin{equation}
\delta_{0} > 0,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \forall u \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, \lVert \left(x-x_{0},u-u_{0}\right)\rVert < \delta_{0} \longrightarrow \left(x,u\right) \in S.
\end{equation}
Replacing $u$ with $u_{0}$, we have the following proposition:
\begin{equation}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \lVert x - x_{0} \rVert < \delta_{0} \longrightarrow \left(x,u_{0}\right) \in S.
\end{equation}
Thus, we have proved the following proposition:
\begin{equation}
\exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \lVert x - x_{0} \rVert < \delta \longrightarrow \left(x,u_{0}\right) \in S
\end{equation}

This proof introduces implicitly where we used the rule of elimination of universal quantification and the elimination and introduction of existential quantification. I think with proper training in logic and rigorous use of English, both the conciseness of English and preciseness of logical language can be combined. Has anyone thought about this type of training for self improvement or for teaching students?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at. The level of rigor or pedantry depends mostly on the mathematical maturity of your audience.

Comment: I think it generally counterproductive and harder to follow than a well-written argument using more ordinary prose and less formalism.

Comment: I agree with @BrianM.Scott. Symbolic mathematics is accepted by very few journals and is excruciating to read and understand. Elegant it is not.

Comment: The reason for this is never to say it is superior to the proofs from mature mathematicians. This is only a suggestion for training students not in mathematics department. Many students like me can accept words like "let ...", "define a function... and the function leads to ...", but we accept without a good understanding. The confusion may not be reflected in reading, but it is often reflected in writing. We may use this style to let students know what they are writing. Then more students outside math department may love math, as they have the feel of MASTERING every piece of proofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I feel much better at formal proofs in logical symbols than the informal proofs in English because the former is much concise and does not cause any confusion. Rules of inferences apply very neatly to them. Note that 'informal' does not imply 'not logically strict.'

But the proof can be too verbose when we keep writing statements in symbols, while each line has only slight changes as you demonstrated. In that sense, the Fitch-style formalization will be a good tool for teaching how to prove propositions in first-order logic. The Fitch-style proof will prevent the proof from being unnecessarily long. In case we have to show the result to the others including publication, we can just translate it into English.

Conclusion: It is a good strategy to prove a proposition in formal proving methods (e.g., Fitch-style) to exclude any ambiguity and translate the result into English.

I recommend you to read 2011 - Barker-Plummer - Language, Proof, and Logic

Comment: This is exactly the book I have read. It is impossible to write proofs all in fitch, but the general structure of proof in fitch is smooth and elegant. Nobody wants to prove something with a lot of quantification symbols, and fitch teaches you how to decompose them into ones without.

Comment: @ZiqiFan Exactly